# Links not working in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

for some reason, not being able to click the links in navbar

layout.jade

```
doctype html(data-ng-app='nearMe')
html
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        nav.navbar.navbar-static-top.navbar-default(role='navigation')
            .container-fluid
                .navbar-header
                    a.navbar-brand(ui-sref='posts') Near Me
                .collapse.navbar-collapse
                    ul.nav.navbar-nav
                        li.active
                            a(ui-sref='posts') Home
        block content
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular/angular.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/app.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/controllers.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/services.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js')
```

Here is my index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    .container
        .row.top-buffer
            .col-xs-8.col-xs-offset-2
                div(ui-view='')
```

Can please tell me what it is I am doing wrong?  Thank you

Comment: do you have states setup for post?

Comment: also dont use .min.js for development since the errors are weird. use the full versions and then change for production

Comment: hi I have states for post

Comment: `ui-sref` needs to equal post then not posts

Comment: hi.  tried it and didnt worked

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Lets see ur state provider please.